# Placing a Django variable inside a URL

Tags: django

I'm creating a list of images, all the images are saved in the same directory so I would just like to change the image name.

I've tried this:

```
<a href="#">                                                         
   <img src="my_server_url/images/"{{ item.name }}".jpg" class="img-responsive">
</a>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, how can I integrate the variable with the URL? thanks

Comment: Is the location /images/ reachable via your Webserver? And: Do you have any failure?

Comment: It is working, ive replaced the variable with an actual image name and it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you put too many '"'. Try this:

```
   <img src="my_server_url/images/{{ item.name }}.jpg" class="img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the quotes.

```
<img src="my_server_url/images/{{ item.name }}.jpg" class="img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you're serving your media and static files. Are the images you're trying to display saved on a model (and hence media) or have they been added to your static files?

You may want to look at the [get_static_prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#get-static-prefix) tag, or ensure that you're using a `RequestContext` and do something like:

```
{% load static %}
{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_URL %}

<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/{{ item.name }}.jpg">
```

Or similar, with the `MEDIA_URL` context variable.